# WebRTC services for live-streaming (7 people)

Tags: android, ios, streaming, video-streaming, webrtc

I have a small problem with choosing service and technology for creating my own project. The service must have live video sreaming (7 people max). I want my project to be supported by desktop browsers, iOS app and Android app. I think about using webRTC and I'd like to use some service for it (tokbox or bistri for instance). Is there somebody who worked with webRTC? What could you advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to be more specific when asking for advice. Of course, at SO there are a lot of people that worked with WebRTC. But what do you want to find out about WebRTC? And be as specific as you can. Please keep in mind that SO is not free research tool.

Comment: You need other software for that, like [OBS](https://obsproject.com/), [Xsplit](https://www.xsplit.com/) or [Geforce experience's ShadowPlay](http://www.geforce.com/geforce-experience/shadowplay). Theoretically you could use WebRTC's screensharing feature, but it's really not meant for live-streaming and you are going to run into problems. Also, screensharing is not yet available in the native APIs, so web only....

Answer (score 0):

We are successfuly maing screen sharing distribution to groups of more than 50 people using [Kurento Media Server](http://www.kurento.org). Unfortunately, we cannot share the code of that project, but you can find a tutorial for webcam distribution (i.e. one to many) that can be adapted to your use case in this link:

- [One-to-many tutorial in Node.js](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node/tree/master/kurento-one2many-call)
- [One-to-many tutorial in Java](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java/tree/master/kurento-one2many-call)

Kurento can also be integrated with the Wowza media server. This enables interoperating WebRTC with other streaming technologies such as RTMP, HTL or MPEG-DASH, which may provide you built-in (high-latency) distribution on iOS.